# sqlite3.OperationalError: 1 values for 3 columns

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert and extract data using a sqlite database, but I keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Database_Section\Dsite.py", line 14, in <module>
    insert("Cup", 4, 5)
  File "Database_Section\Dsite.py", line 10, in insert
    cur.execute(cur.execute("INSERT INTO store(item, quantity, price) VALUES ('?,?,?')", ('item','quantity','price')))
sqlite3.OperationalError: 1 values for 3 columns`enter code here
```

And this is my code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store(item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)')
conn.commit()
     
def insert(item,quantity,price):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(cur.execute("INSERT INTO store(item, quantity, price) VALUES ('?,?,?')", ('item','quantity','price')))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
 impo
insert("Cup", 4, 5)     
     
def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM store")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
     
print(view())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO store(item, quantity, price) VALUES ('?,?,?')"
```

This tries to insert the literal string `'?,?,?'` to the table, and fails because it's a single value and there are 3 columns (as the errors says).

You should remove the quotes surrounding the placeholders:

```
"INSERT INTO store(item, quantity, price) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it then gives me this error:-
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
What can I do????